# Is Secure Javascript Code Possible in Modern Browsers

Tags: javascript, security, client-server

Modern Javascript produces libraries such as OpenPG.js, Crypto-js, with other supporting server side technologies such as Dart and Node. Is it now possible to deliver secure javascript client side?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure javascript"?

Comment: Non Obfuscated javscript code encrypted client side.

Comment: it always has been, that's why god gave us HTTPS...

Comment: Yeah, do you mean secure as in, client can't access the code?  Or secure as in, data intercepted by a hacker can't be understood (encryption etc)?

Comment: I think the answer is "no".

Comment: The client will always be able to see the code and will always be able to see the data. The client's machine can encrypt the data so any intermediate parties would have to break the encryption to see it. HTTPS does this already at a lower level so why you would want to do it in _JavaScript_ I don't know

Comment: Secure in client cant access the code. I spicifically what i am refferring to here. The code is not Obfuscated but encryted.

Comment: @xdrone, then no, not now, not ever

Comment: No, the way JavaScript is served by the server hasn’t changed.

Comment: Well after a bit of research I have come across the following very interesting projects. http://www.jcryption.org/ a javascript openssl encryption and http://www.fourmilab.ch/javascrypt/ a browser-based cryptography tool. Check them out..

Answer (score 0):

**No!** You should never trust the browser since it cannot and will not protect your interests. I highly recommend you to read following articles that explain the whys:

https://tonyarcieri.com/whats-wrong-with-webcrypto
http://blog.zuehlke.com/en/why-is-xss-apache-cordovas-worst-enemy/